# infinispan - Synchronization between nodes -state-transfer -notification

Tags: caching, infinispan

in my application , i have a micro service deployed in two instances in the same machine , the micro service allow me to insert some data in the cache using infnispan. first i started just one instance and i put samed data in the cache , but when i started the second one , i noticed that there is a synchronisation between them... its normal because the second on is join the cluster. (for your information , im using jgroups for clustering ).
so when i call a service to retrive same data for the second instance , it did'nt answer because its in phase of synchronization , he dosent have the data. but when it finishes he return me a response;

so my question is how can i know that the synchronization between these two instances are terminated ?  there is a way in infinispan to notify me that the synchronisation between nodes in infinispan is finished ?

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

That synchronization is called "state transfer" and you can either have it blocking (i.e. nodes wait for the initial transfer before becoming responsive) or non-blocking (which means they immediately respond to requests, retrieving entries remotely if they haven't been transferred yet). 
You can receive an event for the state transfer completion by registering a cache listener for the [DataRehashedEvent](https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/9.4/apidocs/org/infinispan/notifications/cachelistener/event/DataRehashedEvent.html)

You can make the state transfer non-blocking by setting the ["await-initial-transfer"](https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/9.4/apidocs/org/infinispan/configuration/cache/StateTransferConfigurationBuilder.html#awaitInitialTransfer-boolean-) attribute to false on the cache state transfer configuration